# Proof exercide of $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis

If $M(\epsilon)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\epsilon$, then $M(\epsilon)$ is the union of the $\sigma$-algebras generated by $F$ as $F$ ranges over all countable subsets of $\epsilon$

Proof: Let $M = \bigcup_{F\subset \epsilon}M(F)$, we need to show that $M = M(\epsilon)$. First, we will show that $M\subset M(\epsilon)$, observe that for each countable subset of $F$ of $\epsilon$ that $M(F)\subset M(\epsilon)$. Since, $F\subset \epsilon \subset M(\epsilon) \Rightarrow M(\epsilon)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $F$ therefore $M(F)\subset M(\epsilon)$.

Now we need to show $M\subset \epsilon$ but this is where I am sort of lost, any suggestions is greatly appreciated. I know this is similar to another question that was asked but I didn't really like the notation and I wish to follow through with what I have set up already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to show that $M(\epsilon) \subset M$.  Let's try to show that $\epsilon \subset M$.  If $A \in \epsilon$, then the set $F = \{A\}$ is an at most countable subset of $\epsilon$.  So $M(F) \subset M$.  But certainly, $A \in F \subset M(F)$, so $A \in M(F)$.  Thus for any $A \in \epsilon$, $A \in M$.  So $\epsilon \subset M$.  But $M(\epsilon)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\epsilon$, so $M(\epsilon) \subset M$.

**Edit:** And is this homework or for personal enrichment?

Comment: Personal enrichment, should have noted that. I will be taking a graduate course in Real Analysis this semester but I am trying to study ahead and do exercises in the Real Analysis by Folland book

Comment: Ah.  I assumed (Richard) Oberlin was teaching measure again, and I could not even begin to imagine him asking a question like this.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I am guessing you go to FSU?

Comment: Once upon a time!